# How to convert json with id to entity

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, java-ee-8

i have a class Book which have a @ManyToOne relatioshionship with Publisher:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "publisher_id")
    private Publisher publisher;

    //getters and setters etc

}
```

I'm struggling on how to configure the server to accept a post to save a book with the following json structure:

```
{
    "title": "Purpose driven life",
    "publisher": {
        "id": 1
    }
}
```

I want to just send the publisher with only id, and the server associate in this case the book with the publisher with id 1, which is already in the database, i have in my controller to save the book a method like so:

```
@POST
@Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response save(Book book) {
    service.save(book);
    // URI creation and return statement
}
```

So, which configurations i need to make in my server to correct handle this? Thanks.

[EDIT]

I was sending the request to a wrong endpoint, that's why i was getting the errors all this time, after trying to apply the solution on the answer i got the same error and figure out the wrong endpoint.

To send that json to the server there's no need any configuration, the server somehow handles it and serializes.

Thanks for the answer and the comment.

Comment: What happens when you save? Are there any exceptions?

Comment: When i save hibernate tries to persist the Publisher entity and a got a ConstraintViolationException cause the the atribute name is not filled.

Answer (score 0):

Just get publisher before saving the book.

Assume to have `findPublisherById(int publisherId)`

Create a RequestModel:

```java
public class BookRequest {
  private Long id;
  private String title;
  private int publisher;

  //getter and setter
}
```

Now you can use one method to map BookRequest to Book model (put this method whenever you want, i assume you'll put it in service class):

```java
public Book getBookFromBookRequest(BookRequest bookRequest) {
  Publisher publisher = findPublisherById(int publisherId);
  return new Book(bookRequest.getTitle(), publisher);
}
```

Modify `save` into service:

```java
public void save(BookRequest bookRequest) {
    Book book = this.getBookFromBookRequest(bookRequest);
    //save the book
}
```

At this point let's modify your request method:

```java
@POST
@Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response save(BookRequest bookRequest) {
    service.save(bookRequest);
    // URI creation and return statement
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, let me try, but doesnt seem to be a java ee way of doing, i come from Spring Boot and all we need to do is implement a component class which implements converter interface of the given type, is this case Publisher.

Comment: I added some details to my answer. I hope it helps

Comment: Yess, your answer is correct and actually work, but the server converts automatically, theres no need to call findById method.